# machine learning for any cancer diagnosis on image dataset with python

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, machine-learning, scikit-learn

> Blockquote

i am working on this project asssigned by university as final project. But the issue is i am not getting any help from the internet so i thought may be asking here can solve issue. i had read many articles but they had no code or guidance and i am confused what to do. Basically it is an image processing work with machine learning. Data set can be found easily but issue is python python learning algorithm and code

> Blockquote

Comment: If its your final project and it is "assigned" to you, why don't you post this question to your supervisor first?

Answer (score 1):

I presume if it's your final project you have to create the program yourself rather than ripping it straight from the internet. If you want a good starting point which you can customise Tensor Flow from Google is very good. You'll want to understand how it works (i.e. how machine learning works) but as a first step there's a good example of image processing on the website in the form of number recognition (which is also the "Hello World" of machine learning).

https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners

This also provides a good intro to machine learning with neural nets: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXt8qF2Zzfo

One note on Tensor Flow, you'll probably have to use Python 3.5+ as in my experience it can be difficult getting it on 2.7.

Comment: Ok that's a bit clearer. If you want to use svm there is a module in scikit for svm and if you want to know how to implement some of that code check out this article: [link](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/10/understaing-support-vector-machine-example-code/) . You can also find the scikit documentation here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all I need to know what type of data are you using because depending on your data, if it is a MRI or PET scan or CT, there could be different suggestion for using machine learning in python for detection.

However, I suppose your main dataset consist of MR images, I am attaching an article which I found it a great overview of different methods> 
This project compares four diﬀerent machine learning algorithms: Decision Tree, Majority, Nearest Neighbors, and Best Z-Score (an algorithm of my own design that is a slight variant of the Na¨ıve Bayes algorithm)

https://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~karplus/abe/Science_Fair_2012_report.pdf

Here, breast cancer and colorectal cancer have been considered and the algorithms that performed best (Best Z-Score and Nearest Neighbors) used all features in classifying a sample. Decision Tree used only 13 features for classifying a sample and gave mediocre results. Majority did not look at any features and did worst. All algorithms except Decision Tree were fast to train and test. Decision Tree was slow, because it had to look at each feature in turn, calculating the information gain of every possible choice of cutpoint.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:-

Lung Image Database Consortium provides open access dataset for Lung Cancer Images.

Download it then apply any machine learning algorithm to classify images having tumor cells or not.

I attached a link for reference paper. They applied neural network to classify the images.

For coding part, use python "OpenCV" for image pre-processing and segmentation.

When it comes for classification part, use any machine learning libraries (tensorflow, keras, torch, scikit-learn... much more) as you are compatible to work with and perform classification using any better outperforming algorithms as you wish.

That's it..

[Link for Reference Journal](http://www.cmpbjournal.com/article/S0169-2607(13)00353-2/abstract)

Comment: Thanks..  How to apply machine learning algo to classify images ? any reference where i can read about this

Comment: Scikit learn, scikit image, opencv documentations will help you a lot. Check it out..